# Removing items from a nested list Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to remove items from a nested list in Python.  I have a nested list as follows:

```
families = [[0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2, 3],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

I want to remove the entries in each sublist that coorespond to the indexed position of the sublist in the master list.  So, for example, I need to remove 0 from the first sublist, 1 from second sublist, etc.  I am trying to use a list comrehension do do this.  This is what I have tried:

```
familiesNew = [ [ families[i][j] for j in families[i] if i !=j ] for i in range(len(families)) ]
```

This works for `range(len(families))` up to 3, however beyond that I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.  I am not sure why.  Can somebody give me an idea of how to do this.  Preferably a one-liner (list comprehension).

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You almost got it right. Just replace `families[i][j]` with `j` and it works:

```
>>> [ [ j for j in families[i] if i !=j ] for i in range(len(families)) ]
[[1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5, 6]]
```

It can be written a bit cleaner using the `enumerate` function:

```
>>> [[f for f in family if f != i] for i, family in enumerate(families)]
[[1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5, 6]]
```

Or even using `remove` if you don't mind changing the original list:

```
>>> for i, family in enumerate(families): family.remove(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with the last option as it was in fact okay and desirable to change the list in place.

Answer (score 5):

Edited question, removing my answer which was solving the wrong problem.  Also, added additional answer by @Ashwini:

For comparison's sake:

```
root# python -m timeit 'families = [[0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2, 3],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]' '[x.remove(ind) for ind,x in enumerate(families) ]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.42 usec per loop    

root# python -m timeit -s 'families = [[0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2, 3],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]' '[[f for f in family if f != i] for i, family in enumerate(families)]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.87 usec per loop

root# python -m timeit -s 'families = [[0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2, 3],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]' '[ filter(lambda x:x!=i,j) for i,j in enumerate(families) ]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.99 usec per loop
```

These are micro-second, so I think whatever you want to do is fine unless you are going to be doing this a **lot** of times.

Comment: I think the semantics of this is not quite right. It's not that the element at the *index* `i` should be removed from every sublist, but the item `i` itself.

Comment: This is a clever trick, but I think it doesn't quite do what it is intended to do.  (It would work if the latter elements of the outer list were sequences starting at 0).  +1 for timeit though.

Comment: My mistake for misreading the intent of the question (and subsequently for not checking the output to match)

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you want?

```
familiesNew=[ filter(lambda x:x!=i,j) for i,j in enumerate(families) ]
```

**EDIT**

Also note, the reason yours failed is because at the third element of the outer list (`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`) you're trying to get the fifth element in your for loop (`for j in families[i]` == `for j in [1,2,3,4,5]`), but families[i] has a length of 5, meaning the largest index is 4.  Sorry if that explanation is a little unclear...perhaps the following will help clear it up a little:

```
families = [[0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2, 3],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

def f(i,j):
    print i,j,families[i]
    return families[i][j]
#THIS DOES NOT WORK -- but it will tell you where it failed.
familiesNew = [ [ f(i,j) for j in families[i] if i !=j ] for i in range(len(families)) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to modify the original list then try this:**

```
>>>[x.remove(ind) for ind,x in enumerate(families) ]
>>>families
[[1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: This answer is interesting because it does the calculation in place.  Presumably it would return a list of None ... but that might be OK for some applications.

Comment: yes! this list comprehension will return a list of None of length == len(families) and will modify the original list.

Comment: good solution, though usually it's considered impolite to use a list comprehension for side effects.